# MariaDB utf8 problem with some chinese characters

Tags: utf-8, mariadb, cjk

I have some problems with this chinese character:

My setup:
CentOS 7
MariaDB 10.1.48
Standard charset utf8_bin

The character ist only shown as '???'.

I already tried different charsets: ut8mb4, utf16

Any recommendations?
Or is anyone able to diplay the character with a simliar setup?

Cheers

Comment: Please  [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: `` cannot displayed in utf8 - so something is wrong: You cannot store a 4 byte character in a 3 byte character set. Despite this, consider to upgrade to a more recent version of MariaDB. MariaDB 10.1 is eoled.